# REGEX to match this Pattern [LHB][0-9]{12}

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

I need a regex to match this pattern:

- A string 13 characters long
- The first letter must be a L, H, or B (not case sensitive)
- The next 12 characters must be in the range 0-9

e.g. L109878762013 will match while L10/987876/2013 won't

If the pattern doesn't match any of the above criteria, and isn't 13 characters long then it shouldn't be picked up.

What do I need to modify in the regex `[LHB][0-9]{12}` to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should work if you expand the `{12}`, which SQL server does not support:

```
LIKE '[LHB][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: And indeed it does. I've still got 7 minutes before i can mark it correct. Thank you very much.